# What happens when message handler does not call inherited?

Tags: delphi

I have just noticed that one of our very (very) old custom controls (not created by me) has this `WM_SIZE` message handler (I used a `TPanel` here for the demo):

```
TPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TPanel)
private
  procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
end;

procedure TPanel.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  DoSomethingWhenResized;
end;
```

The `inherited` is not being called. the `DoSomethingWhenResized` creates a cached gradient bitmap which is used in the paint process of the control.

Every thing "looks" and behaves fine, but I just wonder if anything could go wrong by **not** calling the `inherited` handler first?

Comment: Depends. The only thing that happens is that the ancestor's code of this message handler is not called. If you handle message by yourself, there's no need to call `inherited`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naturally, if you don't call `inherited` then you lose the behaviour that is implemented in the ancestor controls.  Whether or not this is a problem for you is something only you can decide.  The VCL source shows you exactly what those ancestors are doing.   In your example the first ancestor up the chain to handle `WM_SIZE` is `TWinControl` which does this :

```
procedure TWinControl.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
var
  LList: TList;
begin
  UpdateBounds;
  UpdateExplicitBounds;
  inherited;

  LList := nil;
  if (Parent <> nil) and (Parent.FAlignControlList <> nil) then
    LList := Parent.FAlignControlList
  else if FAlignControlList <> nil then
    LList := FAlignControlList;

  if LList <> nil then
  begin
    if LList.IndexOf(Self) = -1 then
      LList.Add(Self);
  end
  else
  begin
    Realign;
    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
      Resize;
  end;
end;
```

Here `WMSize` calls `inherited`, but there are (currently) no ancestor objects above `TWinControl` that implement this, so the above is what you are missing by not calling `inherited`.  If your `DoSomethingWhenResized` manages your control bounds, sizing, and component alignment of child controls (or if you don't need it to do this) then you're fine.  If you find, however, that the control is not handling these things properly then you might suspect that `DoSomethingWHenResized` has missed one or more of these responsibilities in its implementation.